# Get available stock for all varieties in Shopware PWA (Next.JS)

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using Shopware PWA and created my own buttons for selecting a colour and size. I want to changed the style of a button when stock is empty, but I can't for the life of me find where to get all stock of the varieties. I'm in the `SwProductDetails.vue` and tried the `product` and the `getOptionGroups` refs, but I can only find the stock of the currently selected variety. Where do I find all available stock?

In the default exported frontend from the shopware admin panel it does show the buttons with a different style for empty stock, but I don't know where to look for the stock in the ShopWare PWA module.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the

[`IUseAddToCart` interface / API](https://github.com/vuestorefront/shopware-pwa/blob/3e2daa6db07decc3b6950e6fa02bc34554048418/docs/landing/resources/api/composables.iuseaddtocart.md)

which provides an `getAvailableStock` method.